# DataNitro call function periodically

Tags: datanitro

I am using **DataNitro** to fill in the json data extracted from an url( I am using a function to do this) into an excel file. But I want to update the excel file every 3 seconds without running the function again.

Comment: think you will have to write the timing but in visual basic.  Calling the DataNitro procedure every 3 seconds.   The code inside the timing bit should be:   Application.COMAddIns("DataNitro.DataNitro").Object.RunScript ("YourScriptName.py")